# How to show div when hovering dynamically a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different `a`-tags which gets generated dynamically. Each link will generate an own `div` with different contents so each `div` has an individual content as well as an individual height.

Now I would like to achieve that when hovering an `a` the matching `div` will be shown. The `div` then should be shown at the mouse position and should be position from bottom to top direction so that the `div` is "growing in upward direction" because the links are on the bottomside of the page.

Here is what the code is look like (`$z` is a counter):

```
<a href="<?php echo $link_djv;?>" class="rsshover" id="djvl_<?php echo $z;?>" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline"><?php echo $title_djv;?></p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_<?php echo $z;?>">
    <?php echo $description_djv;?>
</div>
```

I read already through different threads but wasn't able to find a proper way on how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Run Snippet

This is a basic version of what you need. obviously the animation needs work but should give you a good starting point.

```js
class ToolTipControl {
  constructor () {
    this.xCoordinate;
    this.yCoordinate;
    this.links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    this.addEventListeners();
    this.activeLink = false;
  }
  
  addEventListeners () {
    for (let link of this.links) {
      link.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => this.handleMouseEnter(e));
      link.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => this.handleMouseLeave(e));
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.handleMouseMove(e));
  }
  
  handleMouseMove (event) {
    this.xCoordinate = event.pageX; 
    this.yCoordinate = event.pageY;
    
    if (this.activeLink) {
      this.activeLink.style.top = `${this.yCoordinate}px`;
      this.activeLink.style.left = `${this.xCoordinate}px`;
    }
  }
  
  handleMouseEnter (event) {
    this.activeLink = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    this.activeLink.style.maxHeight = '50px';
  }
  
  handleMouseLeave (event) {
    let targetsContent = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    targetsContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
    this.activeLink = false;
  }
  
}

new ToolTipControl();
```

```css
.preview {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="rsshover" id="djvl_123" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">some title</p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_098">
    content 1
</div>
<a href="/" class="rsshover" id="djvl_123" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">some title</p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_098">
    content 2
</div>
<a href="/" class="rsshover" id="djvl_123" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">some title</p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_098">
    content 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to add a mouse over event of your link and then a javascript function to show your div in the right location.  Then you'll need a mouseout even to hide the div again.

what I would start with is change your php code to be:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link_djv;?>" class="rsshover" onmouseover="showDiv('<?php echo $z;?>');" onmouseout="hideDiv('<?php echo $z;?>');" id="djvl_<?php echo $z;?>" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline"><?php echo $title_djv;?></p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_<?php echo $z;?>" style="display:none;">
    <?php echo $description_djv;?>
</div>
```

Then add a javascript function:

```
    <script>
    function showDiv(counter) {
          document.getElementById('djvd_' + counter).style.display = 'block';
       // this is where you'd position your div location

    }


    function hideDiv(counter) {
         document.getElementById('djvd_' + counter).style.display = 'none';
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how exactly do you want your preview to be displayed, but this should help you.

```js
(function($) {
  var $currentElement;
  $('.rsshover').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $currentElement = $('#djvd_' + $(this).attr('id').substr(5));
    $currentElement.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      display: 'block',
      top: e.clientY + 'px',
      left: e.clientX + 'px'
    });
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $currentElement.hide()
  })
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.preview {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="rsshover" id="djvl_1" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">Headline</p>
    </li>
</a>

<div class="preview" id="djvd_1">
    Description 1
</div>
```

Also, please don't put `<li>` tags inside anchor `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS by putting the `div.preview` inside the `a.rsshover`

```css
.rsshover .preview {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .rsshover:hover .preview {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="rsshover" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">1</p>
    </li>
    <div class="preview">
        ONE
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="rsshover" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">2</p>
    </li>
    <div class="preview">
        TWO
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="rsshover" target="_blank">
    <li>
        <p class="headline">3</p>
    </li>
    <div class="preview">
        THREE
    </div>
</a>
```